# Is it possible to have Logarithm with base 1 or 0?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

I am wondering is there any definition that allows logarithm to have base 0 or 1 in real or complex fields (considering Euclidean space)??

Out-coming question is if you can define a logarithm with negative base??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the real numbers, the logarithm is defined as the inverse of the exponential function. The functions $f: x\mapsto 1^x$ and $g:x\mapsto 0^x$ are not invertible, so the quick answer is no.

The longer answer is still no.

The problem is that the fundamental property of any logarithm function is that it satisfies the equation

$$a^{\log_a x} = x$$
for (at least) all values of $x\in(0,\infty)$ (this can further be expanded if we are looking at the complex numbers, but at the very least, the equality should hold on $(0,\infty)$). However, if $a=1$, then no matter what $\log_1 x$ is, for all values of $x$, the expression $$1^{\log_1 x}$$ will be equal to $1$, which, if $x\neq 1$, is not equal to $x$.

I would argue that any function which does not satisfy the equation $$a^{\log_a x} = x$$ is not really a logarithm function in any real sense, thus, the logarithm function for base $1$ does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, what about complex field?

Comment: @MikaelEgibyan The same argument still stands. Even for complex numbers, $1^z = 1$ for all complex numbers, so it doesn't change anything.

Comment: The long answer is that $\log_0 x = 0^x$. Verify with matrices for instance.

Comment: @Anixx That answer is neither long nor correct. It doesn't even make sense. $0^x$ is always $0$, so are you saying $\log_0 x= 0$ for all $x$?

Comment: ...for all values of $x$. I guess, you work with complex logarithm..

Comment: @lonestudent I don't understand what you are saying. Which part of my answer are you commenting on?

Comment: At high school , we learn logarithm as $a^{\log_ax}=x$ where $0<a≠1,~x>0$.

Comment: @lonestudent Sure. So? Did I write anything that contradicts that?

Comment: "The problem is that the fundamental property of any logarithm function is that it satisfies the equation"

$$a^{\log_a x} = x$$
**for all values of $x$**

Comment: @5xum $0^x$ is not always $0$. My longer answer to this question has been deleted yesterday, but you I think, can see it below (given you have 100K reps).

Comment: @lonestudent Oh, I understand what you are saying. It's fixed now. You could have saved us a lot of back and forth if you were more explicit about what you are trying to say in the first place :).

Comment: In split-complex numbers, for instance, $0^{1/2+j/2}=1/2-j/2= \log_0 (1/2+j/2)$, $0^{1/2-j/2}=1/2+j/2= \log_0 (1/2-j/2)$

Comment: @5xum $\ddot\smile$